# select in case or if statement?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is it possible to add a select statement in case or if function in SQL

`select case when :A='do' then (select col1 from table1) else 'n/a' end`;

or

```
select if(:A='do',(select col1 from table1),'N/A');
```

If my parameter is 'do' it should display all the value in table or else it should just display 'N/A'.

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "all the values", do you mean one column or more than one? If more, is "N/A" to appear in all columns?

Comment: Did you try to use WHERE ?

Comment: @Bohemian;all the data in one column.

Comment: @dcieslak,with 'where' will i be able to toggle between 'col1' and 'N/A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Oracle, as per your tag, then neither of your queries are valid as they're not actually selecting from a table.

Perhaps what you're after is something like:

```
select case when :A='do' then col1 else 'n/a' end col
from   table1;
```

Or maybe you're after something like:

```
select col1
from   table1
where  :A != 'do'
union all
select 'N/A' col1
from   dual
where  :A = 'do';
```

You didn't provide any example data, so I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is make all the values of col1 appear as 'N/A' if the bind variable is "do" or whether you only want a single row containing 'N/A'.